# Is it possible to determine the exact EC2 targets of a CodeDeploy deployment via CloudWatch events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-code-deploy

AWS CodeDeploy's model defines an `Application`, which is a long-lived high-level object and represents software that needs to be deployed somewhere. An application can have many `Deployment Groups`, which represent targets (e.g. particular EC2 servers that have a particular combination of tags). A `deployment` is the release of one particular revision of software onto a deployment group defined within an application.

It is possible to get feedback on the progress of CodeDeploy via [CloudWatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#acd_event_types).  Given that EC2 servers can be up or down at the time of a deployment, and given that the tags on EC2 servers may vary over time, is there a way of determining from a CloudWatch CodeDeploy event the exact set of EC2 servers that were targeted by a particular deployment?

Specifically:

1. If a server is down at the time a deployment is launched, will it be targeted for release when it comes back up?
2. If I add a new server with identical tags to the first one after I have done the deployment, or I change the tags on the first server, will the CloudWatch event associated with my CodeDeploy event contain details of exactly which servers were targeted for deployment at the time, even if their current state means that they would not be targeted for deployment if I were to re-release the same deployment?

Comment: The event object contains `deploymentId`. You can use cli or sdk [list-deployment-targets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/list-deployment-targets.html) to get the list of instances associated with the `deploymentId`. Not sure if this is what you are after though?

Comment: OK, just wanted to check that the targets are specific to the actual deployment that occurred, not the current targets that exist within the currently configured deployment group (which may differ from what was actually targeted at the time). I can make another SDK call, had been hoping that the targets would be in the event.

Comment: I should be the actual instance at the time of deployment. This is something that can be relatively easy to verify with few test instances and some simple deployment.

Answer (score 2):

I tested few scenarios using a simple CodeDeploy setup. Deployment group was identified based on instance **tags** only (no ASG). My observations are as follows:

#### Server down at the time a deployment is launched

I simulated this scenario by having a **stopped instance**. The deployment **hanged** on the stopped instance. It would probably **timeout** if I let it hang for long. Once the instance was re-started, the deployment continued.

#### New instances started with the same tag

CodeDeploy **did not detect them automatically**. Had to redeploy the last deployment so that the new instances get detected and run the up-to-date application version.

#### Changing a tag of an instance

The instance with changed tag is **not included** in a new deployment. Thus you end up with one instance running an old version of your application, while the rest run the new version.

#### Deployment id and list-deployment-targets AWS CLI

The `list-deployment-targets` prints out IDs of instances for which the deployment happened at the **time of deployment**. When you redeploy (deployment id does not change in this case), the list will include instances for redeployment. Original list of instances is lost.

#### Note

Deployments to ASG will **behave differently**, since CodeDeploy integrates with ASG through its lifestyle hooks.

Hope this helps.